# Error creating wcf .svc service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have created following svc service given below-

```
public class NewsRest : INewsRest
{
    public string getHomePageNews1()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {

            dt = new ManageNews().getHomePageNews1();
           string json = new Utills().dataTableToJsonString(dt);
           json = json.Replace("task-photo-846b6edc-3b2e-4ff6-ba10-734d64143c1d.png", "task-photo-8d5feed4-d6a1-4ae9-9a72-387ccfda1dc5.jpg");
            return json;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "{}";
        }
    }
}


 [ServiceContract]
public interface INewsRest
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string getHomePageNews1();
}
```

and web config configuration is-

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NewsRestBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15"  />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="UPNews.WebServices.NewsRest" behaviorConfiguration="NewsRestBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="UPNews.WebServices.INewsRest" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MetadataEndpoint"
     contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

but when I am testing this service on WCF test client it gives following error.-

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:57358/WebServices/NewsRest.svc/getHomePageNews1
>    If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access,
>    please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.
>    For help enabling metadata publishing, 
>   please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error 
>   URI: http://localhost:57358/WebServices/NewsRest.svc/getHomePageNews1 Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
>   'http://localhost:57358/WebServices/NewsRest.svc/getHomePageNews1'. Content Type application/soap+xml; 
>   charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:57358/WebServices/NewsRest.svc/getHomePageNews1. 
>   The client and service bindings may be mismatched. The remote server returned an error: 
>   (415) Unsupported Media Type.HTTP GET Error URI: http://localhost:57358/WebServices/NewsRest.svc/getHomePageNews1 There was an error downloading 
>   'http://localhost:57358/WebServices/NewsRest.svc/getHomePageNews1'. The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.

Please tell whats wrong happening here.

Answer (score 0):

You must add to your server configuration to allow MEX (meta data exchange) so that the client can retrieve the generated WSDL. Something like this:

```
<service name="UPNews.WebServices.NewsRest" behaviorConfiguration="NewsRestBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="UPNews.WebServices.INewsRest" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

Comment: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:57358/WebServices/NewsRest.svc/getHomePageNews1'. Sendera:DestinationUnreachableThe message with To 'http://localhost:57358/WebServices/NewsRest.svc/getHomePageNews1' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree

Comment: This looks like the your server and client configuration do not match. Ensure that the the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.